# Issue with TensorFlow Federated docker Installation

Tags: docker, dockerfile, tensorflow-federated

I'm currently working on setting up TensorFlow Federated using Docker. Here's the steps I followed:

Cloned the TensorFlow Federated repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/federated.git
cd federated
```

after the cloning I couldn't find a Dockerfile in the cloned repository, I created one with the following content:

`# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.10.9-slim

FROM jupyter/base-notebook:latest

## Set the working directory in the container

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

## Copy the local requirements file to the container

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential

## Install TensorFlow Federated and any additional Python packages

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir tensorflow-federated 
&& pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

## Copy the local code to the container

COPY . .

## Specify the default command to run when the container starts

CMD [ "python", "./your_script.py" ]
`
I built the Docker image:

`docker build . --tag tensorflow_federated:latest`

I'm getting the following errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0yTb.png)

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you!